# jQuery returning empty on ID search despite IDs being present

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a minesweeper game using jQuery. Right now after starting the game the code creates a bunch of tiles with given IDs such as "M2+3" to represent the coordinates of the tile, while a code in the background runs and checks if said tile is a mine or not. Right now whenever i run

```
$("#GameBoard").on("click", ".Mine", function(foo) {
      const axis = this.id.slice(1).split("+")
      console.log(axis)
      $(this).html(game.clickTile(parseInt(axis[0]), parseInt(axis[1])))
      $(this).removeClass("Mine");
      $(this).addClass("ClickedMine")
      if (game.nearbyMines(parseInt(axis[0]), parseInt(axis[1])) == 0) {
        for(let j = -1; j < 2; j++){
          for (let i = -1; i < 2; i++){
            console.log($(`#M${parseInt(axis[0]) + i}+${parseInt(axis[1]) + j}`))  // This line specifically
            $(`#${parseInt(axis[0]) + i}+${parseInt(axis[1]) + j}`).trigger("click")
        }}
      }
      if (game.tiles == 0){
        $("#start").show()
      }
    });
```

jQuery doesn't find any objects in the DOM, despite there obviously being objects with said ID, and I'm not sure if I'm just hitting some weird jQuery rule with the formatting of my ID names. I first tried changing the names of the IDs, first adding an M ahead of the coordinates since IDs apparently need to start with a letter, then i changed the "," into a ":" and finally to "+" but still no luck.

This is the code used to create the tile map

```
 $("#Button").click(_ => {create_game()});

    const create_game = _ => {
        game = new Game()

        $("#start").hide()
        $("#GameBoard").html("<div id=\"MineField\">" +
    "</div>")

      for(let j = 0; j < game.theight; j++){
        for (let i = 0; i < game.twidth; i++){
        $("#MineField").append(`<div class=\"Mine\" id=\"M${i}+${j}\"></div>`)
      }}

        $("style").append("#MineField {" + 
              "display: inline-grid;" +
              "background-color: grey;" +
              "padding: 10px;" +
              "grid-template-columns:" + " auto".repeat(game.twidth) + ";" +
            "}")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The plus symbol is a CSS operator, which means jQuery is looking for a set of elements. You'd need to use alternative syntax, like `$('[id="M2+3"]')`.

```js
$('#2+3').click(function() {
  console.log('2+3 clicked - ID selector');
});

$('[id="2+3"]').click(function() {
  console.log('2+3 clicked - attribute selector');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="2+3">Click me.</div>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: It's called a combinator, not an operator.

Comment: Yes, a combination operator.